Unable to resolve service for type 'AzureKeyVaultIntegration.AzureKeyVaultHelper' while attempting to activate 'IndexModel'
I have a DLL to fetch the secret from the KeyVault using REST AP.
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace AzureKeyVaultIntegration
{
public  class AzureKeyVaultHelper
{
    // Replace with your Azure AD Tenant ID, Client ID, and Client Secret
    private const string TenantId = "TenantId";
    private const string ClientId = "ClientId";
    private const string ClientSecret = "ClientSecret";
    private const string KeyVaultBaseUrl = "https://testakv123.vault.azure.net/";// Replace with your Key Vault name

    private static readonly HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    private readonly string _keyVaultUri1;

    public AzureKeyVaultHelper(string keyVaultUri)
    {
        _keyVaultUri1 = keyVaultUri;
    }

    // Get OAuth2 access token from Azure AD using client credentials
    public static async Task<string> GetAccessTokenAsync()
    {
        var tokenUrl = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token";

        var requestData = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"grant_type", "client_credentials"},
            {"client_id", ClientId},
            {"client_secret", ClientSecret},
            {"scope", "https://vault.azure.net/.default"}
        };

        var requestContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(requestData);

        var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(tokenUrl, requestContent);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var jsonResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonResponse);

        return json.access_token;
    }

    // Fetch secret from Azure Key Vault
    public static async Task<string> GetSecretAsync(string secretName)
    {
        string accessToken = await GetAccessTokenAsync();

        var requestUrl = $"{KeyVaultBaseUrl}/secrets/{secretName}?api-version=7.2";

        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, requestUrl);
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {accessToken}");

        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var jsonResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonResponse);

        return json.value;
    }
  }
}

This DLL is referenced in the WebApplication below WebApplication:
//using Azure.Identity;
//using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;
 using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
//using WebAppWithKeyVault;
using KeyVaultHelper;
using AzureKeyVaultIntegration;


var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Set up the Key Vault URI (either hard-coded or from app settings)
  string keyVaultUri = builder.Configuration["KeyVaultUri"] ?? 
  "https://testakv123.vault.azure.net/";

 // Register the KeyVaultService as a singleton
 builder.Services.AddSingleton(new KeyVaultService(keyVaultUri));

    // Add services to the container.
   builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

  var app = builder.Build();

 // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
 {
app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
 }
else
{
app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();

The code in the Index.cshtml.cs file code looks like below:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using KeyVaultHelper;
using AzureKeyVaultIntegration;


 public class IndexModel : PageModel
 {
//private readonly KeyVaultService _keyVaultService;
private readonly AzureKeyVaultHelper _keyVaultService1;

public string SecretValue { get; private set; }

 /* public IndexModel(KeyVaultService keyVaultService)
  {
    _keyVaultService = keyVaultService;
  }*/
public IndexModel(AzureKeyVaultHelper AzureKeyVaultHelper)
{
    _keyVaultService1 = AzureKeyVaultHelper;
}

public void OnGet()
{
    // Use the KeyVaultService to fetch the secret
    // SecretValue = _keyVaultService.GetSecret("Test3"); //Using AKV out of the 
box lib
    SecretValue = AzureKeyVaultHelper.GetSecretAsync("Test3").ToString(); 
 //Using REST API
    //SecretValue = await AzureKeyVaultHelper.GetSecretAsync("Test3");
  }
}

My Index.cshtml looks lie this:
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

<div class="text-center">
<h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
  <p>Learn about <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">building Web 
apps 
  with ASP.NET Core</a>.</p>

Secret from Key Vault
<div>
  <p>The secret value is: @Model.SecretValue</p>

I am getting below error:
      Now listening on: https://localhost:7266
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5009
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: C:\Users\routj\source\repos\WebApplication1
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'AzureKeyVaultIntegration.AzureKeyVaultHelper' while attempting to activate 'IndexModel'.
         at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ThrowHelperUnableToResolveService(Type type, Type requiredBy)
         at lambda_method5(Closure, IServiceProvider, Object[])
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.DefaultPageModelFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<CreateModelFactory>b__0(PageContext pageContext)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.CreateInstance()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Why is this error coming?

Are you getting this error locally?

Definitely error in Dependency Injection, KeyVaultService injected but  AzureKeyVaultHelper.

Add AzureKeyVaultHelper in the DI. builder.Services.AddSingleton(new AzureKeyVaultHelper(keyVaultUri));.

Refer this GitHub once

I am able to get the secret by registering AzureKeyVaultHelper in Program.cs file as I mentioned above.

Is your issue resolved ?

The issue is with your Key Vault code and registering Class Library in the Program.cs file.

Your classlibrary is AzureKeyVaultHelper, but you have registered KeyVaultService (you have commented it in Index.cshtml.cs file).

My AzureKeyVaultHelper.cs file:
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class AzureKeyVaultHelper
    {
        public const string TenantId = "****";
        public const string ClientId = "****";
        public const string ClientSecret = "****";
        public const string KeyVaultBaseUrl = "https://harshukv18nov.vault.azure.net/";// Replace with your Key Vault name
        private static readonly HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

        public async Task<string> GetSecretAsync(string secretName)
        {
            var token = await GetAccessTokenAsync();
            var secret = await GetSecretFromKeyVaultAsync(secretName, token);
            return secret;
        }

        private async Task<string> GetAccessTokenAsync()
        {
            var confClient= ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ClientId)
                    .WithClientSecret(ClientSecret)
                    .WithAuthority(new Uri($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantId}"))
                    .Build();

            var result = await confClient.AcquireTokenForClient(new[] { "https://vault.azure.net/.default" })
                                  .ExecuteAsync();
            return result.AccessToken;
        }

        private async Task<string> GetSecretFromKeyVaultAsync(string secretName, string accessToken)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var url = $"{KeyVaultBaseUrl}secrets/{secretName}?api-version=7.3";

                var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
                request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

                var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var secretValue = System.Text.Json.JsonDocument.Parse(content)
                                        .RootElement.GetProperty("value").GetString();
                return secretValue;
            }
        }
    }
}

My Program.cs file:
builder.Services.AddSingleton(new AzureKeyVaultHelper());

My  Index.cshtml.cs file:
using ClassLibrary1;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace WebApplication1.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;
        private readonly AzureKeyVaultHelper _keyVaultHelper;
        public string SecretValue { get; private set; }
        public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger, AzureKeyVaultHelper keyVaultHelper)
        {
            _keyVaultHelper = keyVaultHelper;
            _logger = logger;
        }
       
        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
           SecretValue = await _keyVaultHelper.GetSecretAsync("SampleKey");
        }
    }
}

Output:


Good to accept the solution if it has solved the problem. This is for the benefit of the SO Community, refer SO Link
